# How to create a NOP instruction for iPhone ARM binaries?

Tags: iphone, arm

The NOP opcode for x86/x86_64 is 0x90, but which is the analog on the iPhone with the ARM instruction set?

Comment: A few examples: https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/ab9d4507dacb9ed393c0d326e85d886387732656/v7/nop.S

Answer (score 15):

MOV r0, r0 is traditionally used in ARM code, which has the opcode 0xe1a00000; MOV r8, r8 is used in THUMB code (opcode 0x46c0)

Comment: Does this not have side effects on the architecture?

Comment: @Stefan, I don't think so.  Those are the machine instructions my assembler generates when I put a 'nop' instruction in the source file.

Comment: Apparently Thumb2 has a NOP instruction. See page 5 of http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001l/QRC0001_UAL.pdf

Answer (score 13):

ARMv7 has an actual `NOP` instruction, with the following encodings:

```
    0xbf00  2 byte thumb2 form
0xf3af8000  4 byte thumb2 form
0x*320f000  4 byte arm form
```

When targeting earlier versions of the architecture, assemblers translate `NOP` into the MOV instructions that **moonshadow** listed.

You shouldn't need to use the actual opcodes, as the development tools understand `NOP`.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to add that non-conditional NOP for armv7 is 0xE320F000.

Note that if you are going to patch a file you will need to write bytes in reverse order (little endian) - 00 F0 20 E3